# find correlation between pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, correlation

I have two pandas data frames which I have taken from only one column and set dates column as index, so now I have two **Series** instead.
I need to **find the correlation for those Series**.

Here are a few rows from`dfd`:

```
index      change
2018-12-31  -0.86
2018-12-30  0.34
2018-12-27  -0.94
2018-12-26  -1.26
2018-12-25  3.30
2018-12-24  -4.17
```

and from `dfp`:

```
index      change
2018-12-31  0.55
2018-12-30  0.81
2018-12-27  -2.99
2018-12-26  0.50
2018-12-25  3.59
2018-12-24  -3.43
```

I tried:

```
correlation=dfp.corr(dfd)
```

and got the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 5):

Problem is `dfp` is filled by string repr of numbers, so use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert to floats:

```
correlation=dfp.astype(float).corr(dfd.astype(float)
print (correlation)
0.8624789983270312
```

If some non numeric values solution abaove fail, then use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` - non numbers are converted to missing values:

```
correlation=pd.to_numeric(dfp, errors='coerce').corr(dfd)
```

Comment: I get error  `object has no attribute 'corr' ` for both of your suggestions.

Comment: @SharonAsayag - So `print (type(dfp))` is `DataFrame` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: note there was a problem of `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'` . I fixed it by: `correlation=dfp.astype(float).corr(dfd.astype(float))`.

Comment: @SharonAsayag - Super :)

Answer (score 1):

Can merge the two dataframes and correlate columns

```
dfd['date']=pd.to_datetime(dfd['date'])
dfd.set_index(dfd['date'], inplace=True)
dfd.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)

dfp['date']=pd.to_datetime(dfp['date'])
dfp.set_index(dfp['date'], inplace=True)
dfp.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(dfp,dfd,left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()
df
```

[image]

**Correlate on two columns change(dfd),(dfp)**

```
df['change(dfp)'].corr(df['change(dfd)'])
```

**Outcome**

[image]

Comment: I get `ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: reset index after merge.                                                                                       
                                                                                                                          df = pd.merge(dfp,dfd,left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()